# How to the same thing with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, omniauth

Reading on this [oauth tutorial](http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/twitter-oauth-and-ruby-on-rails-integrated-cookbook-style-in-the-console-updated-for-twitter-1-0/).

I would like to do exactly the same thing using the [Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) gem, to get the access tokens from Twitter's API.

```
#oauth = OAuth::Consumer.new(APP_CONFIG['twitter_consumer_key'], APP_CONFIG['twitter_consumer_secret'], :site => 'http://api.twitter.com', :request_endpoint => 'http://api.twitter.com', :sign_in => true)

# Get the request tokens from the API
rt = oauth.get_request_token
rtoken = rt.token # request token
rsecret = rt.secret # request token secret

# Go to url and click ""Allow access” when prompted
# http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=your_request_token_from_above

# Get the access tokens from the API
at = rt.get_access_token
oauth_token = at.token
oauth_token_secret = at.secret
```

Anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is a good howto, take a look:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/11/using-omniauth-to-make-twitteroauth-api-requests